# How to get regex exact coincidence with a var on Powershell

Tags: powershell

Another one that doesn't seem to have any solution already online.

I have a file with all my volumes and I have a variable where the user writes a volume such as "C" or "D". The problem here is that if I write "D" it will take me every single line that has a D.

I have this code:

```
$unit=Read-Host -Prompt 'Introduce a volume name'
echo "Searching for the volume..."
Get-Volume > volumes.txt
get-content volumes.txt | select-string -pattern "$unit" > exist2.txt
gc exist2.txt | where{$_ -ne ""} > exist.txt

$disk=(Get-Content exist.txt)
echo $disk
```

So the regex should be on the "select-string -pattern" and this is what I've tried so far:

```
get-content volumes.txt | select-string -pattern "/(^|\W)$unit($|\W)/i"

get-content volumes.txt | select-string -pattern "^[$unit]$"

get-content volumes.txt | select-string -pattern '^$unit,'

get-content volumes.txt | select-string -pattern "\$unit\b"
```

All of them returns nothing and what I want to return is the line of the D unit.
For example if I write "C" this it what will be returned

```
C                                     NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: It returns me the first line too and DriveLetter and Friendly have also "D"s

Comment: Yeah that Works, thanks a lot, how can I put this as "solved"?

Comment: Cool :) I have moved my comments into a proper answer, and you can upvote/tick that to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why PowerShell is an object oriented shell, so you don't have to do this string scraping. A PowerShell way to do this is:

```
Get-Volume | where-object { $_.DriveLetter -eq $unit -or $_.FriendlyName -eq $unit }
```

The output on screen does contain a header line, but that's not in the content, the command returns objects, and if you do nothing with them, PowerShell formats them into a table for showing on screen.

If you want to see it without headers

```
Get-Volume | 
    where-object { $_.DriveLetter -eq $unit -or $_.FriendlyName -eq $unit } | 
    format-Table -HideTableHeaders
```

but if you're going to work with it more in the script, don't convert it to text, it will only make it harder to work with later.